# Bootstrap forms & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Ok to make the question clearer:

Heres my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });  
    var ajax_load = "<p>Loading</p>";  

    //load() functions
    var loadUrl = "ajax/test.php";
    $("#addvariation").click(function(){
        $("#test").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });
});
```

This should work off a button click and return a simple textual paragraph in my php file:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="addvariation">Add Variation?>
```

This is the div test:

```
<div id="test">text goes here</div>
```

When i click the button, the page jumps to the top if that helps.

Firebug doesn't give me an error, but if I remove all the bootstrap code it works.  Is there a known bug with Bootstrap 3 forms?

Comment: Half your code is missing, and you need to take the jQuery tutorial. The first step is wrapping it in a function so it executes once the page is ready.

Comment: This is actually on the click of a button, and works fine when  Bootstrap isn't on the page.

Comment: You still need to wrap the click handler in a jQuery ready function. Again, time to read the tutorial. That alone will likely help significantly.

Comment: what does the html of #test look like?

Comment: Should the # go in front of test in the script or be removed?

Comment: check jquery.js wheater it's included twice.